# How do I imitate the behaviour of a pressed button in Android?

Tags: android, button, android-styles

I'm trying to make a custom button, that behaves just like a 'pressed button' in Android with my own background images.

Pressing changes my button's image (color is darker), but I can't seem to get the focussed / focussed&pressed states right. 
When you release your finger on the default button there is a circle filling the whole button but it won't happen with mine.

That's my code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/fertig_focussed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/fertig_focussed_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/fertig_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fertig_regular" />

</selector>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The expading circle is a [`RippleDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html) rather than a `StateListDrawable`. `RippleDrawable` is available only on API 21+.

Comment: That's what I was searching for, thanks! Unfortunately the min. API doesn't work for me, is there a way to implement it just for devices that are on 21+?

Comment: Well yeah, you can have a default StateListDrawable in res/drawable folder. Then you can have a RippleDtawable in res/drawable-v21 which will be used on API 21+.

Answer (score -1):

That's because android check stats in the order and get the one matching first.

You need put "pressed" first, focus pressed second, then focused.

Comment: Since all states specify both pressed and focused attributes, there's no contest.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Although you're right that it's the order that matters, i tried your combination and a few others and none would get me my wished result...

Comment: You're right but i'm not sure that you can press a button but not getting focus on it. Therefore swapping order may solve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. Apparently I can arrange the focused and focused/pressed in any way I want, all it gives me is the default and pressed background when pressing on the button. But when I swap the default and the pressed state, the button is not clickable anymore, so the order does matter, at least between those to states. Am I missing something?